# Обновление контента страницы через определённый промежуток времени

Tags: javascript

Вот скрипт обновления страницы <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">

А мне нужно чтоб обновлялась не вся страница а только контент страницы, куда надо вставить этот код  $.load()
Хочу сделать текстовую трансляцию футбольных матчей на сайте ucoz, а как это осуществить не знаю, нужен наверно ещё скрипт шаблона, подскажите если есть возможность. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    // $.load()
}, 20000); // раз в 20 секунд
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать long polling

Comment: А поточнее как его использовать?

Answer (score 0):

Если пошел разговор про long poling и comet-сервера, то можно глянуть в сторону [WebSocket](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), [узнать как это использовать WebSocket на PHP](http://bohuco.net/blog/2011/01/php5-websocket-example-a-simple-chat/), только из этого примера вам нужна одна половина (сервер - клиент), эдакий полу-чат :-)